# Email exist check not working while copy paste the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my email exist check its working fine, But when I am copy paste the value it's not working.

> Jquery validation check

```
personal_email : {
    required: function () {
        return ($("#formhiddval").val() == "1");
    },
    email: function () {
        return ($("#formhiddval").val() == "1");
    },
    remote : {
        depends: function(){
            return ($("#formhiddval").val() == "1");
        },
        param: {
            url:  "{{ url(ADMIN.'/checkemailexistsEdit') }}",
            type: "post",
            data : {
                candidatekey: '{{$candidateDet["candidatekey"]}}'
            }
        }
    }

},
```

> Email exist ajax check

```
protected function checkemailexistsEdit(){
    alert('ser');
    if (Request::ajax()) {
            $data = Request::all();
            if ($data['personal_email']) {
                $user = candidates::candidateEmailException($data['candidatekey'],$data['personal_email']);
                if ($user) {
                    return 'false';
                } else {
                    return 'true';
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: what u mean by copy pasting not working?

Comment: That means if i copy and paste already existing email, it doesnot showing error its simply moving to next page

Comment: What's the context for all this? How do drag and drop mails from where to where? What software is involved? AFAICS the code could be applied to so mayn different applications incl. some that don't act on drag and drop by intention.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#yourtextboxid").on('keyup mouseup keydown focusout', function (e) {
     //write your jquery code here and check all the conditions.
 });
```